# Windows from external drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have a questions about Ubuntu 16.04LTS and external drives. Right now I have a SSD hard drive with Ubuntu on it and another one(regular) with Windows 10. I still sometimes need to look up for files in my Windows drive and now what I'm doing is swapping between drives when I need something from the Windows drive. My question is: Is there a more sophisticated method for doing this(for example converting my Windows drive to an external) ?

Note: My Windows drive is not external in the moment of speaking, but i can convert it. Also my SSD is not big enough to support dual-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can convert it to an external drive, just after connecting it go to terminal and run this command:

> sudo os-prober

this should find the Windows on your other drive. then use:

> sudo update-grub

and whenever you boot the computer you will see Windows beside Ubuntu in the grub menu.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So is this some sort of a dual-boot or ?

Comment: Yeah, this is a dual boot, grub doesn't care about the drives it only looks for bootloaders. (as far as they use the same firmware like UEFI. )

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you again for the answer much appreciated